# Why does encode favor static properties over instance properties?

Tags: swift

Given a struct with a static and instance property that share a name:

```swift
struct MyStruct {
    // The version on the type
    static let version = 1

    // The version on the instance based on the static version
    var version: Int = MyStruct.version
}
```

If I add custom `Codable` conformance, the container will favor the static over the instance var. Ex:

```swift
extension MyStruct: Codable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        try container.encode(version, forKey: .version) 
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case version
    }
}
```

Then go to encode an instance:

```swift
let myStruct = MyStruct(version: 2)
let encoded = try! JSONEncoder().encode(myStruct)
try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyStruct.self, from: encoded) // MyStruct version 1
```

I can solve this issue by qualifying with self, `container.encode(self.version, forKey: .version)`. But that's not the point.

This is weird. Why is this happening?

Comment: FWIW, I'm unable to reproduce this behavior in the Xcode 11 beta. Seems like this may have been a bug that has since been fixed.

Comment: I just updated... it seems to have to do with whether a default is set. What's weirder is that if you try and remove the default then the synthesized initializer breaks...

Comment: Try removing the default value on the instance variable and you'll see what I mean. However if you change the name of the static var then everything works as expected.

Comment: Hmm, even with your updated code I’m not seeing this behavior when I run it in a playground. Are you on Xcode 11 beta 2?

Comment: I can reproduce this, and I do not see what you mean about "qualifying with self": that changes nothing.

Comment: @matt if you change `try container.encode(version, forKey: .version)` to: `try container.encode(self.version, forKey: .version)` then it works.

Comment: Not in my test. Nor do I see why that would matter; the meaning of `version` does not change.

Comment: @Jumhyn using 10.2.1

Comment: @matt I agree that it *should* encode the same way with or without self but in practice I'm seeing different results.

Comment: @JoeSusnick Ah gotcha. As best I can tell, this is a bug that has been fixed in the latest version of Xcode, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.